# How to run locally AWS .Net7 AOT lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, .net-7.0

I have made .Net7 AOT lambda function to trigger S3 bucket. First problem is that on Release after deploy the function does not get appsettings.json. I already made "Copy always" and:

```
private static IConfiguration ReadConfiguration()
        => new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
```

Also every time when I try to run lambda locally I have this error:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'No connection could be made
> because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:5050)'
> Here is my launchSettings.json and main method:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Workflow.Lambda": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API": "localhost:5050",
        "AWS_PROFILE": "default",
        "AWS_REGION": "us-east-2",
        "EventBus": "https://ssssssss",
        "EventBus": "https://ssssss"
      }
    },
    "AWS Mock Test": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "%USERPROFILE%\\.dotnet\\tools\\dotnet-lambda-test-tool-7.0.exe",
      "commandLineArgs": "--port 5050",
      "workingDirectory": ".\\bin\\$(Configuration)\\net7.0",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API": "localhost:5050",
        "AWS_PROFILE": "default",
        "AWS_REGION": "us-east-2",
        "Lambda.Logging__LogLevel__Default": "Debug",
        "EventBus": "https://ssssssss",
        "EventBus": "https://sssss"
      }
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker"
    }
  }
}

private static async Task Main()
    {
        Func<FileUploadedEvent, ILambdaContext, Task<FileUploadedEventResponse>> handler = FunctionHandler;
        await LambdaBootstrapBuilder.Create(handler, new SourceGeneratorLambdaJsonSerializer<LambdaFunctionJsonSerializerContext>())
            .Build()
            .RunAsync();
    }
[JsonSerializable(typeof(ServiceMetadata))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(ExecutionDetails))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(TransferDetails))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(FileUploadedEvent))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(FileUploadedEventResponse))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(S3FileLocation))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(HttpStatusCode))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(string))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(bool))]
[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
public partial class LambdaFunctionJsonSerializerContext : JsonSerializerContext
{
 
}
```

I have read a lot examples but I never found the solution how to debug AOT lambda.